# Visual Studio deleted my Desktop while doing Publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I accidentally published my C# project into the desktop folder, while the "Delete All files in destination" was checked, and all of my important files and folders there were deleted!

How can I restore them? It's extremely important.

Comment: If you have deleted files on your computer, stop using the computer immediately. Use another computer to load a recovery program on a memory stick, and run that on the affected machine. You may be able to recover the files, but it is not guaranteed. From this point on, always take backups.

Comment: I have the same problem about this. I published my project to desktop and my all files has gone . It is terribly irritating that an easy publishing process caused this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to recover them with this utility:

https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Also, have you checked the recycle bin? The files might be still there.

Comment: Today a coworker accidentally selected the project folder to publish to, also with the  'Delete Files' option selected. When he published, it literally deleted the files it was trying to publish. This feature is something to be used very cautiously. We also used Recuva.